# How do I add a break between a formula thats an active timer?

Tags: google-sheets, timer, breakpoints

How do I add a break between a formula that runs a timer?

Currently my formula runs like `=IF(ISBLANK(C26),"",NOW()-C26)` but is it possible to stop the timer between certain times of the day? I don't want the timer to continue from 1:00 AM to 6:00 AM.

Timer visual:

[image: Timer visual]

I haven't tried much of anything since I'm still new to all this sorry.